# how to get value from radio button to a variable in swift 5

Tags: swift, variables, uibutton, radio-button, uikit

[Need to save ther value from the radio button to a variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITfj0.jpg)

```
@IBOutlet weak var userButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var propertyButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func btClicked (sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonArray = [userButton , propertyButton]
    buttonArray.forEach {_ in 
        $0?.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Comment: use can use btn.tag to save value you need and then use it as you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a variable to store the value of button

```
var strVal = ""
```

create two different outlet for both button

```
@IBAction func btnUserClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    setValue(isUser: true)
}
@IBAction func btnPropertyOwnerClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    setValue(isUser: false)
}
```

the setValue(isUser : Bool) method will store your selected button value and change image of button according to selection

```
func setValue(isUser : Bool){
    if isUser{
        strVal = "User"
        btnUser.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle-fill"), for: .normal)
        btnPropertyOwner.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), for: .normal)
    }
    else{
        strVal = "Property Owner"
        btnPropertyOwner.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle-fill"), for: .normal)
        btnUser.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

the image 'circle' is your default image that is already on button and the image 'circle-fill' is to indicate whether or not your button is selected.

or you can use sender.tag property of button :
[image: add tag from your interface builder]

```
@IBAction func btnUserClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //setValue(isUser: true)
    if(sender.tag == 0){
        strVal = "user"
        btnUser.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle-fill"), for: .normal)
        btnPropertyOwner.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), for: .normal)
    }
    else{
        strVal = "property user"
        btnPropertyOwner.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle-fill"), for: .normal)
        btnUser.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: no, it deselect the previous selected button. i tested it and and it works fine, after that i posted this answer.

Comment: Thanks bro for the code it really helped me

Comment: you can ping me anytime if you need any help. i'll provide you best possible solution :)